# How can I sign a transaction without a private key?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

after connecting to the bag and signing the transaction, I want to do the transaction without requesting confirmation. My main goal is to make a transaction without asking for final confirmation to the wallet.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You cannot sign a transaction without a private key. If the private key is handled by a wallet you have to check if the wallet support signing without user intervention. Some wallets like metamask doesn't allow it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction has already been signed, there is no need to go through the wallet. You can send directly to some node, using a JSON RPC node. You can use the services of Infura, Moralis, Alchemy, among others. There are several companies that do this. But keep in mind that to sign the transaction you need to have the private key of the account that will be making the request.

Comment: I use moralis and I have to sign it every time I connect to my wallet. Is there a way I can get the private key automatically so my users do not have to enter it each time?

Comment: It depends. Apparently it's your users that are sending the transaction, so they will need to sign the transaction. There's no way you can get their private key. Going through the wallet is normal on dApps, don't worry about it. It is possible to go straight to the node, without going through the wallet, only if you are the one sending the transaction every time (using your address), not your users.